# How can server Side Google Tag manager be implemented for Android?

Tags: android, server, google-tag-manager

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data#send_data_from_other_sources

This bit of information for mobile support on GTM is not helping me proceed on how to use sGTM for mobile.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need help on implementing GTM server side via Android app. The procedure to do so as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data#send_data_from_other_sources is not elaborate. If someone who has tried a working mobile eGTM can help on this?